# Youtube Videos on android

Tags: android, youtube

I had to place some youtube videos on android by searching a keyword

. Then after the user clicks it should play the respective video.

I don't know how to implement this. Please help on retrieving you-tube videos based on search. how to start it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reading the [YouTube-API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)?